# Follow link after second click

Tags: jquery, touch, hyperlink

I have a simple navigation that contains a nested sub navigation. I've set up jQuery to add a class on click to show/hide the sub navigation on the top-level items. However I'd like the browser to follow the link through after an item has been clicked once.

So instead of:
- First click: Adds class which shows sub-nav
- Second click: Removes class which hides sub-nav

It would behave like so:
- First click: Adds class which shows sub-nav
- Second click: Follows link

Comment: some code would be useful...

Comment: Include code!! But here is some advice, you can check status of sidebar when click on your parent navigation. If sidebar is showing, navigate your page with parent navigation's url, else,  show sidebar

Comment: My current code is irrelevant, just a simple jQuery function to add a class on click. My question is how to capture the second click on the same element.

Comment: Not my business, but don't you think it can distrub the user ? How can he know he have to click two times on the link ?

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. This may well not end up as a final solution, but it's something I'd like to demo. @T.S.'s answer below to simply use `hasClass` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `addClass`, `removeClass` and `hasClass` for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/uP7wX/3/